how to change the placeholder color of Input Tag antd
I want to change the color of the placeholder of the Input tag. Using Ant design with React js.
`
       import { Input, Select, Space } from 'antd'

                    <Input
                      className='mobStyle'
                      style={{ width: '225px', height: '38px', 
                      background: '#ffffff00', color: '#fff' }}
                      onChange={e => {
                        const rawValue = e.target.value
                        const trimmedValue = rawValue.replace(/\s+/g, '')

                        onChange(rawValue)

                        const isValid = /^[0-9]*$/.test(trimmedValue)

                        if (!isValid) {
                          setError('email', {
                            type: 'manual',
                            message: 'Invalid mobile number'
                          })
                        } else {
                          setError('email', {})
                        }
                      }}
                      onBlur={onBlur}
                      value={value}
                      placeholder='Enter mobile number'
                    />


                    **Style.css**

                     .mobStyle .ant-picker-input 
                         input::placeholder { color: #f0f0f0;
}

I've tried this, but it's not working at all. Let me know if anyone has any ideas.`

I got the answer, Sunddenly it's working.
.mobStylet::placeholder {
color: #ffffff;
opacity: 1;
}

Try below solution it should work,

.className::placeholder  {
color: 'red';
}

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/688sp3
